# Can Kinect outline statue skeletons

Tags: c#, c++, kinect

If I were to want to detect the skeleton of a statue, could the Kinect do it?

I went out to a park and actually pointed a Kinect at some statues, but they couldn't recognize the skeletons.

**Is there any way to get a Kinect to recognize art piece skeletons?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing what the Kinect can identify as a person is not something the SDK gives you power over. However, something that looks enough like a human will be assumed to be a human. If these statues are too tall/short, far away or don't fit reasonable color or depth requirements to be a real person it is unlikely that they will be assigned a skeleton. It will also have difficulties assigning skeletons to things that are curled up like The Thinker.

So the short answer is yes, with the right art pieces the Kinect will automatically detect the skeleton. But most sculptures it most likely will not.